# startActivityForResult sometimes cause main Activity finish and removed from the activities stack

Tags: java, android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have a main `app A`, use **startActivityForResult** to start `app B`.

Everything goes fine but recently sometimes `app A` has been finished and removed from the activity stack (without any error prompt).

`App B` is still running well without any problem.

After I check for the activity stack, `app A` was gone and `app B` is still there (**adb shell dumpsys activity** command).

Anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: what you mean? a little detail more?

Comment: Hi, Can you provide a [verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem?

Comment: have call finish() method after startActivityForResult()

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin I make a launcher-like desktop app A, when user click the other app-icon(B) on my desktop, it creates an intent then use startActivifyForResult to open B. So the Activity Stack will be [peek]B->A[Bottom].  In every app B(made by unity), it has a button call Close, and will call Application.Quit() Method to close the app, then A will Resume again (Not refresh) .  It's worked for most Bs, but in some situation, A restart again. So it breaks something.

Comment: @Mohammadnabil Nope, i won't finish A, i need it run in background.

Comment: Another question that i think could be, if B cost high RAM and CPU resource, and A still running in background and cost high cpu resource. Does A has probability killed by the android system?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) of the `onDestroy()` method of Activity. It's said :

> Perform any final cleanup before an activity is destroyed. This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

The system could choose by itself to kill your activity A if it consider it needs more place. That's what append to you.

As said in the doc, you could avoid it by Override the `OnDestroy()` method and check if it's finishing by user call or by system call using `isFinnishing()`. Then you could for example call `super.onDestroy()` only if it's a user destroy and not a system one. Be careful this mean the system will never be able to kill your activity by itself so you have to make sure you call `finnish()`